# How can break generator function by throw error inside redux saga in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generics, redux, redux-saga

I have this function inside redux-saga

```js
function* CheckUserIsAuth() {
  try {
    const user = yield call(getCurrentUser);
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) throw new Error(null);
    const data = yield call(createUserDocument, user);
    const dataSnapshot = yield data.get();
    yield put(emailSignInSucc({ id: dataSnapshot.id, ...dataSnapshot.data() }));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(emailSignInError(error.message));
  }
}
```

I want to break the try and catch error if user is `null`

I tried to throw error using the code above but it still went to `emailSignInSucc` and gave me `null` as string.

That means it complete function and does not break it

Comment: If it went to `emailSignInSucc` then `user` wasn't `null`

Comment: @Aleksey when i log user in the second line it show me it's null

Comment: If it is `null` - you'll get to the `catch` block

Comment: Probably your action creator `emailSignInError` uses the same action type as `emailSignInSucc` instead of creating the new one

Comment: @AlekseyL. thank for the solution , the problem was in action type

Answer (score 0):

Check `user` and what they are returning.
Perhaps `user` is an empty object and the error is not triggered.

If `throw new Error ()` is called then the code will continue to run in `catch`

Comment: i'm print user in the second line and it returned null